# How would this inequality change under manipulaiton?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Take the equality $g(y) = f(x)$, where $f(x), g(y) < c$ for some constant $c$.  Then we can write $g(y) = f(x) < c$, but how would the inequality change if we instead wrote $0=f(x)-g(y)$?  How does the inequality portion change with other manipulations? For example could we say $f(x) + g(y) < 2c$?

Comment: Are you inadvertantly assuming $c > 0$?

Comment: But even then if $c > 0$ and $f(x) - g(x)$ we could have $f(x_0) =0$ and $g(x_0) =-5,287$ so $f(x_0) - g(x_0) =5,287 > c > 0$.

Comment: @fleablood ya, the functions and c should both be greater than 0

Comment: Are you assume the functions are strictly non-negative?  Or that the functions are withing an *absolute* value (i.e. $|f(x)| < c$ and $-c < f(x) < c$?  Otherwise there is no conclusion.  $F,H < c$ means $-H > -c$ and $F-H > F-c$ which is unlimited below and has no specified upper limit. and $F-H < c-H=c+(-H)$ which is unlimited above ($c-H > 0$ but can be *anything* $>0$) but has no specified lower limit.

Comment: @fleablood yes I assume the functions are strictly positive

Comment: In that case $0 < f(x) < c$ and $0 < h(x) < c$ so $-c < h(x) < 0$ so if you add those together $0 + (-c) < f(x) + (-h(x)) < c + 0$ or $-c < f(x)-h(x) < c$ or  $|f(x)-h(x)| < c$.  Alternatively:  $f(x) - h(x) < f(x)$ and $h(x)-f(x) < h(x)$ so $|f(x) - h(x)| < \max(f(x), h(x)) < c$.... But the functions being strictily positive is a *vital* piece of information that should have been included!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $0 \le f(x) < c$ and $0 \le h(x) < c$ (you didn't specify that the functions were strictly non negative) then

$f(x) - h(x) < f(x) - 0 = f(x) < c$ and $f(x)-h(x) > f(x) -c > 0-c =-c > -c$.

So $-c < f(x)- h(x) < c$ or $|f(x)-h(x)| < c$.

.....

We can generalize that if

$a < f(x) < b$ and $c < h(x) < d$ then

1)  $a+ c < f(x) + h(x) < b + d$ and (so if $0\le f(x) < c; 0\le h(x)<c$ then $0 \le f(x)+h(x) < 2c$

2) $-d < -h(x) < -c$ so  $a-d < f(x)-h(x) < b-c$ (so if $0\le f(x) < c; 0\le h(x) < c$ then $0-c < f(x)-h(x)< c - 0$)

......

If the inequalities are one sided then

$f(x) < b$ and $h(x) < c$ then you can do $f(x) + h(x) < b+c$.  But you can't subtrace $f(x)< b$ and $-h(x) >c$ so $f(x)-h(x) < b-h(x)$  And $b-h(x) > b-c$ but ... you can't combine... all you know is both $f(x)-h(x)$ and $b-c < b-h(x)$ but you can't compare $f(x)-h(x)$ to $b-c$.

(Or you know $f(x)-h(x) > c-h(x)$ and $b-(h(x)) > b-c $  so you know both $f(x)-h(x) > c-h(x)$ and $b-(h(x)) > b-c$ but again, you can't compare $f(x)-h(x)$ to $b-c$.

.....

However if the inequalities are "opposite sided"

So $f(x) < b$ and $h(x) > c$ then you *can* do subtraction but not addition:

because $h(x) > c$ means $-h(x) < -c$ and so $f(x)-h(x)=f(x) + (-h(x)) < b+(-c)=b-c$.

(and $-f(x) > -b$ so $h(x)-f(x) > c-b$)

Answer (score 1):

Note that in your example $g(y)$ and $f(x)$  and $C$ are constants so they follow the regular rules on inequalities.

For example, if $f(x)=g(y)<C$ then you have $ f(x)+g(y)<2C$   but you can not say $$ f(x)-g(y)<C$$ because we do not know whether $ C>0$ or $C<0$

You can add inequalities and you can  multiply them by a positive number but you can not subtract them.